# Non-static method t3lib_extMgm::typo3_loadExtensions() should not be called statically

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I'm trying to setup a local instance of my typo3 project. which was built in typo3 4.1. 
For the purpose of upgrading to 6.2 I've to setup a dev instance in my machine. But it shows a lot of warning and errors. Is it due to php version  ie, 5.4 in my machine?. I dont know what exactly creates this error.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I know that it's strange. But when I've updated the TYPO3 core to 4.5 the installation/ modification of compression level value is failed.

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['compressionLevel'] = '3'
```

I set this value to zero

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['compressionLevel'] = '0';
```

Now the warnings and errors are gone. Any idea about this answer will be highly appreciated.